# set httpclient timeout in android

Tags: java, android, httpclient

First it system.out "network found" ,and at the end I see no network.“code” doesn't come out 
       public class NetUtil {
        public static boolean checkNet(Context context) {

```
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = manager
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if (info != null && info.isConnected()) {
        System.out.println("network found");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
                CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 1000);
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
                CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 1000);

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.baidu.com");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

            int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            System.out.println("code:" + code);

            if (code == 200) {
                System.out.println("success");
                return true;
            } else if (code != 200) {
                System.out.println("failed");
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    System.out.println("no network");
    return false;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 1500);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to set timeout for http requests this way

```
int timeoutConnection = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
int timeoutSocket = 5000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
```